# How does SaveFrom.net work for YouTube videos?

Tags: html, youtube, dns

I was wondering how does SaveFrom.net work for YouTube videos as downloading YouTube videos requires you to get the source (HTML) of the video in question and then extract the links. However, this is not possible due to the Same Origin Policy, unless you use a Java applet that gets the source for you. But SaveFrom.net does not do that? Does anyone here have any idea what SaveFrom.net uses to get the HTML source of the YouTube video.

Also, getting the HTML source using server side techniques such as PHP's file_get_contents(url) does not work as YouTube videos can only be downloaded by the same IP address that gets the HTML source.

Comment: Where you ever able to figure this out?